# Angular 9 - Cannot find a differ supporting object 'getData()

Tags: angular9

I am getting this error trying to bind my control to its data. Here is some relevant code.
Template.

```
<tree-control [nodes]="getData"></tree-control>
```

Component.

```
 public getData(): Observable<Array<any>> {
        const assets: any = this.service.get('url', headers);
        return assets;
    }
```

Anything I have found so far is not helping. Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you assign a function (`getData`) to the `nodes` property. I **assume** you want to assign the data from `getData` to it instead.

Secondly, the call to `this.service.get` is **probably** not being executed. Reason for that is that you do not `subscribe` to, what I assume, is a http-call that returns an `Observable`.

To fix this, you can do the following:

```
export class Foo {
  nodeData: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private readonly service: YourService,
  ) {
    this.nodeData = this._getData();
  }

  private _getData() {
    return this.service.get(...);
  }
}
```

Inside your template you can then `subscribe` and `unsubscribe` to the data automatically by using the `async` pipe.

```
<tree-control [nodes]="nodeData | async"></tree-control>
```

For all that to work I **assume** your `service.get` method returns an Observable.

Comment: Ys, you are correct about not properly subscribing. But the real problem wast returning an object instead of array.